# How to load custom font in a-frame?

Tags: aframe

I need to load a custom font with no-standard character in a-frame (currently 1.0.0 version); I've generated the custom zip file, using [enter link description here](https://msdf-bmfont.donmccurdy.com/) which creates one json file and different PNGs files (in the aframe docs, it seems it should be just one PNG), following the guide in the docs (https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/text.html#non-ascii-characters)

it's stated "**Once you download your custom msdf font zip file, extract it and rename *.png to *-msdf.png, then put both png and json files to your A-Frame directory.**", but, what is meant for "A-Frame directory"? I've referenced the files with both a relative and absolute path but it seems it doesn't work

EDIT: now i get this error in console

```
THREE.WebGLState: TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at Object.texImage2D (aframe-master.js:27470)
    at uploadTexture (aframe-master.js:28387)
    at setTexture2D (aframe-master.js:27939)
    at WebGLTextures.safeSetTexture2D (aframe-master.js:28819)
    at SingleUniform.setValueT1 [as setValue] (aframe-master.js:23479)
    at Function.WebGLUniforms.upload (aframe-master.js:23938)
    at setProgram (aframe-master.js:32143)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (aframe-master.js:30878)
    at renderObject (aframe-master.js:31625)
    at renderObjects (aframe-master.js:31595)
```

Comment: Make sure your are serving your files via [local server](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/installation.html#use-a-local-server). If it doesn't work share link that reproduces the issue. [Glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframe) is a good option

Comment: i'm working on an angular 2 app, so i was trying to get them from the assets folder, i'm sorry but due to enterprise policy i can't share relative code, neither i've time to reproduce a sample one :/

Comment: Make sure your files are hosted on a [local server](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/installation.html#use-a-local-server) Unfortunately without more information and visible code it will be hard to provide more specific advice.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/aframe-s4xh1a
hi again, 
here a recreated a sample of an aframe scene, with angular.